# Android System Write Manager

Tags: android

I'm am attempting to create a system app. I have some older code that was given to me to modify, and the old code has an object called `SystemWriteManager` that is imported from `android.app.SystemWriteManager`.

The code to initialize the object is this:

```
SystemWriteManager sw = (SystemWriteManager) mContext.getSystemService("system_write");
```

However, when I attempt to use this code, the import is not found. What do I need to do to import and access this class?

Comment: HI did you find any solution for this?